# SMS not received : messageContact REST API method

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

I'm trying to send an SMS from Marketing Cloud using the messageContact REST API. 
Here is my request :

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/Mzo3OXXX/send
Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {{accessToken}}
    {
    "Subscribers": [
    {
       "MobileNumber": "33650102913",
       "SubscriberKey": "mysubscriberkey"
    }
    ],
        "Subscribe": true,
        "Resubscribe": false,
        "keyword": "FID_SMS",
        "Override": true,
        "messageText": "Hello it's a test message"
    }
```

I have received this response :

```
{"tokenId": "dWN4QkJTLVhwMGFaSG5rWGdBejc4QTo3Njox"}
```

But i haven't received any SMS.

Does anyone know of a solution to this ?

Your help will be so much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What's the locale of the test phone number?

Comment: It's a french phone number. The Local is FR

Comment: If you do this quick query: `select _MobileNumber AS MobileNumber from _MobileAddress`, does the phone format match what's in your API call?  I've found the REST API to be picky about the mobile number format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to try.

Firstly, you need to check the delivery status of the message using [this method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getQueueMODelivery.htm).

Simply make a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
GET /sms/v1/queueMO/deliveries/dWN4QkJTLVhwMGFaSG5rWGdBejc4QTo3Njox
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If that doesn't provide any insight, then I would check any AMPscript or personalization strings used in your message template. If the message can't be interpreted by OMM at send time, then the `tokenId` will still be returned, but the message will not be sent.